# How to remove ranges from an array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist

How to remove ranges from an array in C# Like with `ArrayList`?

```
ArrayList myAL = new  ArrayList();

myAL.Add( "The" );
myAL.Add( "quick" );
myAL.Add( "brown" );
myAL.Add( "fox" );
myAL.Add( "jumped" );
myAL.Add( "over" );
myAL.Add( "the" );
myAL.Add( "lazy" );
myAL.Add( "dog" );   
myAL.RemoveRange( 4, 3 );
```

How can i achieve the same with string array object???

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Generic Lists expose a `RemoveRange()` method. You can convert your array to a list, then remove the range, then convert back to an array:

```
var myList = myArray.ToList();
myList.RemoveRange(index, count);
myArray = myList.ToArray();
```

To remove only one item at a specific index you can use `RemoveAt()`:

```
var myList = myArray.ToList();
myList.RemoveAt(index);
myArray = myList.ToArray();
```

Comment: I'd assume one would only be using an array rather than a list if they wanted some statically sized buffer rather than the resizing a list provides. Given that, they're buffer is now smaller and can get overrun if not careful. I think we have to ask ourselves if we really want a smaller array or if we want to zero out values in a statically sized array. I got here while searching for the latter.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to iterate through the indexes that you need, then copy them to a new array, as arrays can't really be edited in that fashion, hence why array lists are about.